# GNOME Ubuntu 15.04 interchanging keyboard layouts

Tags: 15.04, keyboard-layout, language-support

I have Ubuntu 15.04 with Gnome 3 installation where English (US) is the first keyboard layout and Russian is second. After the system boots up English is used by default and after I switch to Russian for the first time the layout being used is still English, although layout switcher displays "ru". And when I switch again it displays "en", but it is actually Russian.

It wasn't a big deal before I have replaced En-US with English International, because it still acts just like En-US: I can use international chars with compose key only while English stays English before I switch layout for the first time. Can anyone help me to solve this?

My system lang is set to En-US and formats are US if it does matter.

Comment: Can you please copy your "P.P.S." to an answer and accept that answer to mark the issue resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in Question by OP

> Just noticed that I always use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> to switch between layouts. But I now I've tried to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and everything works as expected!

Comment: This solves my problem, but doesn't solve the alt+shift issue. I'd preffer to use it instead of win+space

Comment: Yes, but this should be working. I don't see why I should be forced to use one working shortcut when I'm used to a different setup. What if it collides with my work flow? Proprietary vendors enforcing their rules and limiting users = different story, this happening in FOSS = not acceptable. Quirks like these happen all the time and it's really annoying. Take someone who works as a translator and needs to switch quickly between languages.

Comment: Umm okay, submit a bug report then? [ubuntu.se] do not make Ubuntu.

Comment: I would love to @Tim, but I don't know which package should I file a bug report for. I've tried about anything from the modifiers' menu, not even the mentioned ALT+Space works. I usually use the right Shift key because it's the only one I don't use for anything and it's the quickest way for me. I don't want to use other options because I mainly use graphics applications with custom shortcuts that would intervene.

Comment: @Tim I found eventually the package (I hope) and posted the bug here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1470130